# How to use an .ENV file with a website

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, browserify, api-key

I've made a few node.js bots and web applications that have used .env variables along with the [dotenv package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to hold all of the API keys.

However, Im currently working on a website that uses node.js with browserify and this method doesn't seem to work. Whenever I try to output the value to the console or use the value in the code it returns undefined.

***How would I fix this, or if .env's simply don't work on the web, how would I hide these values?***

my .env example

```
ID = B1CRL2WDIW2553
SECRET = 41445d2b99b33ede3ebce0421900b8e9
```

my js example

```
const dotEnv = require('dotenv').config({path: './.env'});
console.log(process.env.ID);
```

example of the return statement
[image]

Comment: dotenv doesn't work in the browser, it's a node module that needs access to the file system, which the frontend doesn't have

Comment: _how would I hide these values_ you don't put secret values in your frontend. If you need to request something with the key, do that in your backend. However you try to hide something in the frontend, everybody will be able to see it

Comment: Have a look at [envify](https://github.com/hughsk/envify)... besides that you should never expose **secret** keys on your frontend, only use this plugin to check build environment or maybe replace **public api keys** during build time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding the API keys and privileged info to the firebase database and then checking for user authentication before handing over the information. A tutorial can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/